# Запуск ContentProvider

Tags: android

Всем добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, когда именно происходит вызов метода `onCreate()` в `ContentProvider`?

Я думал при первом вызове `ContentProvider`-а из `ContentResolver`-а или `Loader`-а, но почему-то вызов произошел при запуске приложения.